AWS MSK throwing error "org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException:"
i have a AWS MSK setup.

I have spinned up a new AWS MSK cluster.
Created IAM Role to communicate with this AWS MSK cluster.
Created Ubuntu EC2 Instance.
Attached IAM role.
Followed the Official Documentation.
Testing it by creating a sample Topic.
I get this error..

Error while executing topic command : Authorization failed.
[2024-10-16 10:27:31,946] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Authorization failed.
(kafka.admin.TopicCommand$
Browsed Internet for many approaches, but those didn't work.
Please help me in resolving this issue.

Can you also add your IAM policy which you attached to the Iam role, how are you trying to create the Topic

We're going to need more details about the contents of the IAM policy you created and how you're attaching or to your code. Refer [mcve]. Otherwise, AWS Support will be a better resource than Stackoverflow

in addition to prev comment, attach a content of the property file you supply to --command-config param of your create topic command.

My AWS MSK Kafka Cluster setup has been completed, Thanks for your support.
